# How to insert a value form java to database mysql...?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, mysql-workbench

I have searched to insert a value from application java into a mysql table.
Following there's my code. The result of it is a long row of error, but the first row is: `java.sql.SQLException:` Before start of result set

```
        Connection con = null; //oggetto di connessione

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //connessione 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/autonoleggio", "root", "");//connessione vera e propria
                                //quarto va cambiato col nome del database creato         

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dati"); // persone ->tabella presente nel database 

            if(targa.getText().equals(rs.getString("Targa")))       
            {
                Statement insideStatement = con.createStatement(); 
                ResultSet insideResultsSet = insideStatement.executeQuery(
                        "INSERT INTO dati (Cliente) VALUES ('"+inserisci.getText()+"');"
                    );
                /*String query;
                query="INSERT INTO dati (Cliente) VALUES ('"+inserisci.getText()+"');";                 
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);    
                statement.executeUpdate();
                statement.close();  */
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with php.

Comment: Try remove the semikolon at the end of your insert. Where exactly appears the problem?

Comment: the problem is resolved but now i don't see the modifications. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The `ResultSet` object is sort of an iterator on the result returned from the database. Like any iterator, it starts **before the first element**, and needs to be advanced to point to it. In short, you're missing a call to `ResultSet#next()`:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dati");

if (rs.next() && targa.getText().equals(rs.getString("Targa")))  {
// Here -^
```